# Unable to change height of a BoxlLayout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to change the height of a BoxLayout nested inside of another BoxLayout.  I've tried more than a dozen combinations of size, size_hints and height but nothing seems to work. The problem is no matter what I do the BoxLayouts inside of the "ContainerBox" BoxLayout, these BoxLayouts are always the same size. How do I change the heights of nested BoxLayouts?  I want to use the kv language to set the heights not the python code.

Python

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

class ContainerBox(BoxLayout):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ContainerBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Header(BoxLayout):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Header, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Toolbar(BoxLayout):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Toolbar, self).__init__(**kwargs)     

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    f_username = ObjectProperty(None)
    f_password = ObjectProperty(None)   
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)     

class LoginApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ContainerBox()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

Kv file

```
# kivy 1.7.1
<LoginScreen>:
    f_username: username
    f_password: password
    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, 200
        pos: root.pos
        row_default_height: 10
        rows: 3
        cols: 2
        padding: 20
        spacing: 10     
        Label:
            text: 'User Name:'
            color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
            font_size: 24
        TextInput:
            id: username
        Label:
            text: 'Password:'
            color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
            font_size: 24
        TextInput:
            id: password
            password: True
        Label:
        Button:
            text: 'Login'
            background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
            background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
            font_size: 24

<Header>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        height: 100
        size_hint_x: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        Label:
            text: 'Dealer App'
            color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
            font_size: 48


<Toolbar>           
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        height: 36
        size_hint_x: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        pos: root.pos
        spacing: 5  
        Button:
            text: 'One'
            background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
            background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
            font_size: 16
        Button:
            text: 'Two'
            background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
            background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
        Button:
            text: 'Three'
            background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
            background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
        Button:
            text: 'Four'
            background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
            background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1


<ContainerBox>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Header:
        Toolbar:
        LoginScreen:
```

Comment: What you have looks good to a quick check. Can you elaborate on what is wrong?

Comment: I should have been more specific on why it wasn't behaving as I would like, I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to your double-nested layouts. For example, you have `ContainerBox`, which is a `BoxLayout`. So you add to that `Header`, which extends `BoxLayout` but has a `size_hint` of `(1, 1)`! You set the `size_hint` on the `BoxLayout` contained inside `Header`, but that doesn't affect the `Header` itself.

So, to fix this: remove the extra nested layouts, like so:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    f_username: username
    f_password: password
    size: root.width, 200
    pos: root.pos
    row_default_height: 10
    rows: 3
    cols: 2
    padding: 20
    spacing: 10     
    Label:
        text: 'User Name:'
        color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
        font_size: 24
    TextInput:
        id: username
    Label:
        text: 'Password:'
        color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
        font_size: 24
    TextInput:
        id: password
        password: True
    Label:
    Button:
        text: 'Login'
        background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
        background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
        font_size: 24

<Header>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    height: 100
    size_hint_x: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    Label:
        text: 'Dealer App'
        color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
        font_size: 48


<Toolbar>           
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    height: 36
    size_hint_x: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    pos: root.pos
    spacing: 5  
    Button:
        text: 'One'
        background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
        background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
        font_size: 16
    Button:
        text: 'Two'
        background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
        background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
    Button:
        text: 'Three'
        background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
        background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
    Button:
        text: 'Four'
        background_normal: 'white_20x20.png'
        background_color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed the issue.  But the solution added all of the unused space to the top of the window not to the bottom as I would have expected. So I added an empty BoxLayout after LoginScreen to move the unused space to the bottom of the window. Is there a way to re-size the window on non-mobile devices so I can control the size of window on my computer?

Comment: On desktop you can resize the window by dragging the corners just like any other window. From code, you can do `from kivy.config import Config`, then `Config.set('graphics', 'width', 1024)` and `Config.set('graphics', 'height', 700)`.